# javascript date validation

Tags: javascript, validation

Assume in my text box user enter like

18-06-2010 ,

Validation RULE if date is greater then current date then program should through the validation error like ,

PELASE ENTER PAST OR CURRENT DATE, DONT CHOOSE FUTURE DATE ,

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The date format you've specified is not recognized by javascript. Here's a script that makes some minor validity checking, but still some rough assumptions that the value entered conforms to the format above, and tries to construct the date string '2010/06/08' out of that.

```
var txtDate = document.getElementById('myTextBox').value;
var dateParts = txtDate.split('-');

if(dateParts.length != 3) {
    alert('invalid date!');
    return false;
}

var testDate = new Date(dateParts[2] + '/' + dateParts[1] + '/' + dateParts[0]);

if(isNaN(testDate.getDate())) {
    alert('invalid date!');
    return false;
}
```

Implement further error checking as you see fit. Once you know `testDate` is a date, you can compare it the current date: `testDate > new Date()`